# Is it possible to register Docker containers in Landscape?

Tags: docker, landscape

I currently run a self-hosted version of Landscape and also a number of docker containers. Is there a process to registering containers in Landscape, particularly if they are Docker containers?

I suspect that this is better handled in something via Openstack Autopilot (or whatever Canonical pushes). But maybe you can build/modify images with the landscape client-server configuration? I haven't tried, as I'm pretty green with containers still, and use pre-built ones from linuxserver.io.

Anyway, is there a process for integrating Docker with Landscape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly try (I expect you could get *something* working), but it is not officially supported.  Docker containers are meant to be immutable containers that run single applications.  Landscape is a full machine system management tool.  Look at [LXD](https://www.ubuntu.com/containers/lxd) for a supported container environment that presents full manageable "system-like" containers.

Official [service description of Ubuntu Advantage](https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/ubuntu-advantage/service-description) from Canonical, of which Landscape is a piece:

> Excludes: ...
>   - Landscape seats for Docker containers.

Comment: Ah, I see - that's probably why I wasn't able to find anything obvious for getting this set up - you're not really supposed to, anyway!